# How to separate .text section into a 4K aligned address in Linux ELF

Tags: linux, linker, elf

is it possible to separate the `.text` into the 4K aligned pages. For example, I wrote a simple program and used `readelf -a a.out` to dump the section headers:

```
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  ... ...
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        00000470 000470 000023 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        000004a0 0004a0 000060 04  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS        00000500 000500 000342 00  AX  0   0 16
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS        00000844 000844 000014 00  AX  0   0  4
```

How can I put `.text` into a 4K aligned page (e.g., Addr for `.text` be 0x1000)?

Thank you!

Comment: *Why* do you care about section alignment? Unlike *segment* alignment (segments are *already* aligned, see `readelf -Wl`), *section* alignment almost never matters after the final link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool responsible of the issue you post is `ld(1)`  (the linker)  It has a complete manual describing the scriptable language used to align pages and create the final program.  Just have a read to that manual (I'm referring to the ld manual, not the manual page)

Once you have read it, you can create a miniscript file that, based on the standard linux script, forces `*(.text)` segments to be page aligned and use it to link your program.